# Non-constant index into uniform array CG Shader

Tags: graphics, shader, skinning, vertex-shader, cg

According to [this nVidia CG tutorial](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/CgTutorial/cg_tutorial_chapter02.html) (and my own experience) accessing uniform arrays in CG shaders with a non-constant index is either inefficient or unsupported (more often than not, unsupported it seems).

My question is; how can I circumvent this problem?

I am currently writing a GPU skinning shader in which I pass an array of bones (4x4 matrices), which I need to access using an index stored in a vertex attribute (specifically, a float4 vector who's components are cast to ints). Obviously, because of the limitations mentioned above, this doesn't work...perhaps I'm missing a better method of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is indeed the common way of doing it, e.g. (this is HLSL but essentially the same -- note the global uniform 'boneArray')

```
float4x3 CalcBoneTransform(float4 blendWeights, float4 boneIndices)
{
  // Calculate normalized fourth bone weight2
  float4 weights = float4(blendWeights.x, blendWeights.y, blendWeights.z , 1.0f - blendWeights.x - blendWeights.y - blendWeights.z);
  // Calculate bone transform
  float4x3 boneTransform;
  int4 indices = boneIndices;
  boneTransform =  weights.x * boneArray[indices.x];
  boneTransform += weights.y * boneArray[indices.y];
  boneTransform += weights.z * boneArray[indices.z];
  boneTransform += weights.w * boneArray[indices.w];
  return boneTransform;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! It turns out that it was, in fact, possible to do this for my platform (Playstation Mobile) however there was an undocumented quirk that means a single uniform array may only be a maximum of 256 bytes (so an array of four 4x4 matrices). Once I'd discovered this, it was a simple matter of splitting my bone array down into individual 256 byte chunks.